# Equating value after testing for nullability in querydsl

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I am using `querydsl` with `spring-data-jpa`. When a value is retrieved from my rest controller, it can or cannot be `null`. Lets assume that I have following class:

```
@Entity
class Person {

    @Id private String name;

    private int age;
}
```

I have created a `BooleanExpression` as below:

```
public static final BooleanExpression hasName(String name) {
    return QPerson.name.isNotNull().and(QPerson.name.eq(name));
}
```

When this is executed by `PersonRepository#findAll(...)`, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: eq(null) is not allowed. Use isNull() instead
    at com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.SimpleExpression.eq(SimpleExpression.java:127) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]
```

Can you please help me in fixing this exception?

Comment: I think it is saying that your argument "name" is null. How about a guard for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Exception seems to say that the argument to hasName is null. Try:

```
return name==null ? QPerson.name.isNull() : QPerson.name.eq(name);
```